# Rewrite URL causes infinite loop

Tags: https, url-rewriting

In IIS 7, I want to force all pages to go to https by adding the following to my web.config but this causes infinite loop.

```
<rewrite>
        <rules>
            <clear />
            <rule name="Redirect to https" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="(.*)" />
                <conditions>
                    <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="off" ignoreCase="true" />
                </conditions>
                <action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}{REQUEST_URI}" redirectType="Permanent" appendQueryString="false" />
            </rule>
        </rules>
    </rewrite>
```

I have tried to disable rule on all virtual directories/application as suggested here, http://blogs.msdn.com/b/kaushal/archive/2013/05/23/http-to-https-redirects-on-iis-7-x-and-higher.aspx, with no luck.  Does anyone have any idea why? Thank you!

Comment: I'm having this same issue. Have you worked it out yet?